# How can I trigger change detection from outside my angular2 app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-components, angular2-changedetection

I have an angular2 app. There is a service which is used in many components. This service provides a static method (which can be used from outside the angular app to update the value:

```
class MyService {
    static _value: any;

    get value(): any {
        return MyService._value;
    }

    static updateValue(value: any): void {
        MyService._value = value;
    }
}
```

In my components I use the service and value likes this:

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
    get formattedValue(): string {
        return 'the value is ' + String(this.myService.value)';
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when I call the static function `window.MyServiceClass.updateValue(3)`, the change detection does not detect the change and the output value is still the old one.

My solution is currently to have a `EventEmitter` in my service, which can be subscribed by components depending on the value. The `EventEmitter` emits each time, the value is changed. The components subscribe to the `EventEmitter` in the `ngOnInit()` method, have the `ChangeDetectorRef`, call `detectChanges()` when the emitter emits and unsubscribe from it in the `ngOnDestroy()`.

But I don't like this solution, because I have to subscribe and unsubscribe in each component and need the `ChangeDetectorRef` injected.

Is there a possibility to trigger a global change detection? So the service can trigger this detection when the value is updated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can check buy navigationStart event.Check the below code  router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
            .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
                console.log(event);
                // You only receive NavigationStart events
            });

Comment: but how can I trigger the change detection?

Comment: You can use event listener

Comment: Currently I'm using an event listener. But I want to know, if it's possible without one.

Comment: Yes you can. You can use  this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (evt) => {
      console.log('Clicking the document', evt);
    });

Comment: Ok, I think you do not understand what I want to know...